# Finding number of Innodb pages to read

Tags: mysql, innodb

Is there any way to find number of pages that needs to read when querying for a set of pks?
`Eg., select * from Table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6);`
Now is there a way to find the innodb pages that'll be read for the query?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dbs.se! Interesting question (+1)! Do you mean how many disk blocks will be retrieved by the query? Those in cache or on disk? Both, I suppose? I'm not sure that MySQL exposes that information - *c.f.* PostgreSQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907377/shared-hit-cache-in-postgresql).

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way to *accurately predict* the number of pages that *will be* read.

One could *estimate* the number of blocks by assuming an average number of consecutive rows per block.  "100" is a simple estimate that often works.  So, unless the rows are big, `id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)` would *probably* involve one page.

If the ids are scattered all over the place (as is 'always' the case with UUIDs, MD5s, etc), then you could *estimate* one page per id.

If you mean *physical* reads *from disk*, the number is often zero -- because things tend to become cached in the "buffer_pool".

There is a way to find the *exact* number of reads *after* running the query.

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS;
```

Then look at the `Handler%` and `Innodb%read%` values.  There will be a lot of values (and they change from version to version), so I cannot provide much detail.

If you would like further discussion, provide the version number of MySQL, the output of that `SHOW`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

> A table T (a,b,c,d .... z) has clustered index pk (a,b). In disk table T occupies n pages. That can be found using mysql.innodb_table_stats.clustered_index_size of that table. How to estimate the number of pages for a certain value of a?

Since `a` is potentially not-unique, we must first find out how many rows have `a=123`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM  t WHERE a=123;  -- let's call that a_ct
```

The "+1" is because:

- If there are no rows with a=123, it will still have to probe the table to discover that.
- After scanning all the rows with a=123, it must read one more row to realize that it has run out of such rows.

As you noted:

```
SELECT n_rows / clustered_index_size AS rows_per_block
    FROM mysql.innodb_table_stats
    WHERE database_name = '...'
      AND table_name = '...'
```

rows_per_block is something of an average, but the value can be much larger or much smaller.  In particular, if there are 'big' `TEXT`, `BLOB` or `JSON` columns, rows_per_block will be low.  It can even be less than 1.  This is due to the big columns being put "off-record".

If you don't fetch the big columns, they don't count in the page-read-count.  This an argument *against* blindly doing `SELECT *` and in favor of listing the needed columns explicitly.

(I don't know of a way to fix the computation due to off-record pages.)

So the *estimate* of pages that will need to be read:

```
(a_ct / rows_per_block) / + 0.5
```

The `+0.5` is because sometimes multiple rows will all be in one block, sometimes will be split across two 'consecutive' blocks.

"Read" means (1) look in cache (the buffer_pool); then, if not present, (2) fetch from disk.

Terminology:  You have used the term "page"; I am using the term "block"--referring to InnoDB's 16KB blocks.  That is the unit by which all data and index operations operate.

"T occupies n pages" -- This "n" could include free blocks or non-leaf-node blocks of the Data's BTree.  And, depending on where n comes form, it may include blocks in secondary indexes.  Note:  The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data and occupies 1% (another "Rule of Thumb") extra space in addition to the space taken by the data.

For huge tables, I make this simplifying assumption:  All non-leaf nodes of any index (PK or secondary) are fully cached in the buffer_pool.  But non-leaf nodes of the data are never cached.  This makes it easy to simply focus on the number of blocks needed to read the data (just as your question does).

In reality, some non-leaf nodes will need to be fetched from disk and/or some leaf nodes will be cached.  Those two estimation errors sort of cancel each other out.  (Another Rule of Thumb.)

Non-"huge" tables in today's production machines tend to be fully cached.  Hence no read I/O is needed for `SELECTs`.  Every 'write' operation needs at least one *disk* write for ACID.  That is another, longer, discussion.  For now, I will point out that any write operation needs to do roughly the same "read" effort as its first step.  And *some* block writes are delayed/cached in the buffer_pool, thereby not delaying the competition of the write SQL.

Comment: A table *T (a,b,c,d .... z)* has clustered index *pk (a,b)*. In disk table *T* occupies **n** pages. That can be found using *mysql.innodb_table_stats.clustered_index_size* of that table. How to estimate the number of pages for a certain value of *a*?

Comment: @ArunSR - I copied your example into my Answer, then discussed it thoroughly.